# How accurate is the AWS WAF Geographic match rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-waf

I enabled the AWS WAF and added a [geo match rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/waf-rule-statement-type-geo-match.html) to block all requests from a specific country. The rule does not use the *Forwarded IP header* but the *IP address in the web request origin*, which is also the AWS-recommended configuration.

I noticed that this rule blocked a request from an IP address of range `94.26.208.0 - 94.26.215.255` which according to WHOIS belongs to *Yemen Telecom Networking Team* and is apparently situated in Yemen. WAF blocked the IP associating it with the specific country that should be blocked, which is not Yemen, not a neighboring country and not even in that region.

Why was that request blocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IP address always rotate so you have to live with some margin of inaccuracy, in my opinion.

According to #24 FAQ, it's 99.8% accurate: https://aws.amazon.com/waf/faqs/

Comment: Thank you, that FAQ #24 was well spotted!

Comment: Why would the IP address range rotate between providers? The IP address range is assigned to a telecom provider in Yemen, it doesn't rotate IMO.